# Unable to integrate Angular Material into Angular Standalone Component

Tags: angular

Facing this issue with angular standalone component integration with angular material:

> Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you
> need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the
> `CommonModule` instead.

[Here is a screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihx3y.png)

I tried importing `BrowserAnimationsModule`and `BrowserModule` in `main.ts` as I am using standalone component.

Comment: Show us the imports of the relevant component, the providers in `main.ts`. In the standalone world you add `provideAnimations()` into the `main.ts` `bootstrapApplication`‘s providers (2nd argument)

Comment: after passing provideAnimations() as second argument ,it is working fine.many thanks @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 0):

To add Angular material in your project you can use this command

> ng add @angular/material

Then you can impot required module in your app.module.
For further reference you can go through this

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Just import CommonModule in app.component.ts and all others modules in the same way. It helped me, but I suppose there is a way somehow to make it in main.ts file, but I didnt find it. There not a lot of information how to import modules to main.ts or app.component.ts in standalone components. I would be glad if someone share this information.

And dont fully understand. Do we need to import for example MatButtonModule, everywhere where we need it, or it can be imported once somewhere in main.ts and be common for all components.

From the error, you dont need to import BrowserModule, it is have been loaded already.

In main.ts you need to import provideAnimations in providers and call this method provideAnimations() instead of BrowserAnimationsModule.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
```